# VueJS child to parent boolean value for hide component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, parent-child

Hi all and thank for helping :)

Context :
*In my child i want pass a boolean to the parent for hidden a component in the parent if user clicked*

in my child component  ( *name : connexionDesktop* ) :

```
<button v-on:click="$emit(childMessage)"> Start </button>

data () {
  return { 
    childMessage: true
  }
}
```

in the parent i try :

```
<connexionDesktop v-if="fromChild == false " v-on:childToParent="childMessage"> </connexionDesktop>


data () {
    fromChild:false
}


methods: {
    childMessage (value) {
       alert('from child' + value );
       this.fromChild = value
    }
}
```

but that's not working ... i think i am a noob :D i can't send a message from child to parent ^^""

can you help me ? thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for the `$emit` method should be the event name. So your code should look better like this:

```
// child component
<template>
 <button v-on:click="handleClick"> Start </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data () {
     return { 
      childMessage: true
     }
   },
   methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$emit('update:parent', this.childMessage)
    }
  }
}


</script>
```

Then in the parent component, you listen for the event and pass in the value the child emitted to a local value of the parent like so:

```
<template>
   <connexionDesktop v-if="fromChild == false" @update:parent="fromChild = $event"> 
   </connexionDesktop>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data () {
    return {
     fromChild: false
    }
   },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's stated in [the docs on $emit here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), the first parameter is the custom event name.

You can do something like this:

```
<button v-on:click="$parent.$emit('childToParent', childMessage)"> Start </button>

data () {
  return { 
    childMessage: true
  }
}
```

and in the parent:

```
<connexionDesktop v-if="fromChild == false " v-on:child-to-parent="childMessage"> </connexionDesktop>

...

data () {
    fromChild:false
}


methods: {
    childMessage (value) {
        alert('from child' + value );
        this.fromChild = value
    }
}

...
```